# PHP / Magento - caching strategy

Tags: php, magento, caching, redis, apc

I am creating an application using Magento and am trying to think of the best tools for caching.

There are a few choices and I am not experienced enough to fully consider everything and hoped for some advice here.

So the choices are:

Sessions

```
Redis, Memcached, Apc
```

Backend

```
Redis, Apc
```

The application will be running on a single server so I would probably rule out Memcached.

So the choice is between Redis and apc or a mixture of the both.

What would be best here?

Or is redis and apc caching different things so should be used together.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend usage of Redis, there is really nice module https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis which does all work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see Memcached is faster, because it can use multiple cores, which any decent magento hosting has. Memcached is integrated out of the box, so you dont need to hassle with Redis.

[Is memcached a dinosaur in comparison to Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873249/is-memcached-a-dinosaur-in-comparison-to-redis)